# udev and Garmin eTrex Vista HCx in ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev, garmin

I have a Garmin eTrex Vista HCx GPS and would like to use it in ubuntu 9.10.

At first I just plugged the thing in and it recognised it as a "Garmin eTrexHCx microSD" in the nautilus "computer:///" window. Great! I try to access it, and, no matter how many times I double click, nothing happens.

I'm guessing that linux isn't treating it as a standard usb disk and I need to do something extra.

Comment: What are the right-click options? Is "mount" there?

Comment: nope, no mount option.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to place/retrieve files from the unit, you need to enable *mass storage mode*.
The button for it (USB Mass Storage) can be found under `Settings > Interface`